# Perl: Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I have a Perl hash (from some legacy code) but am unable print out the   the keys.

```
  if (ref $val eq ref {}) {
    print "Keys: " . keys $val . "\n";
```

e.g. here's the output I get:

```
VAL: HASH(0x7ff0898eda70)
Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref
```

I've read this [Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080143/type-of-argument-to-keys-on-reference-must-be-unblessed-hashref-or-arrayref) but not sure how to apply it in this case.

Is there a way of fixing this?

====

UPDATE

I've also tried:

```
    print "Keys: " . keys %$val . "\n";
```

but still get `Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref`

UPDATE 2

I can see I have the key `a_key` but I'm unable to print out its values. E.g. debugging with `Carp::REPL` I get:

```
$ print $val;
1$ HASH(0x7fb1e0828f00)    
$ print %$val;
1$ a_keyARRAY(0x7fb1e0828e28)
$ print %$val{'a_key'}
Compile error: syntax error at (eval 412) line 63, near "$val{"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at (eval 412) line 63, <FIN> line 6.
$ print $val{'a_key'}
Use of uninitialized value in print at (eval 413) line 63, <FIN> line 7.
1
```

UPDATE 3

Using `Data::Dumper` in the REPL I get:

```
$ print Dumper( $val );
$VAR1 = {
          'a_key' => [
                     'long_value'
                   ]
        };
1$ print Dumper( %$val );
$VAR1 = 'a_key';
$VAR2 = [
          'long_value'
        ];
1$ print %$val[1]
Compile error: syntax error at (eval 450) line 63, near "$val["
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at (eval 450) line 63, <FIN> line 44.
$ print %$val{'a_key'}
Compile error: syntax error at (eval 451) line 63, near "$val{"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at (eval 451) line 63, <FIN> line 45.
$ print $val[1]     
Use of uninitialized value in print at (eval 452) line 63, <FIN> line 46.
```

Comment: @ikegami can you elaborate?

Comment: I just re-ran the code and got the same error message.

Comment: The `.` sets scalar context, but when you fix this `print "keys: ", keys(%$href), "\n";` you'll get all keys concatenated into one word. You can do `print "$_ " for keys %$href; print "\n";`, or for one per line `say for keys %$href;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you have a precedence problem. You are doing

```
keys($val . "\n")
```

instead of

```
keys($val) . "\n"
```

---

Secondly, the syntax for [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)<sup>[1]</sup> is

```
keys HASH
```

meaning you need

```
keys(%$val)
```

---

Finally, you are calling `keys` in scalar context, which returns the number of keys in the hash. Call it in list context to get the keys of the hash. For example,

```
say "Keys: ", join ", ", keys(%$val);
```

---

1. There were a few versions where Perl experimented with allowing `keys $ref`, but the experiment was discontinued in 5.24. Avoid that!

Comment: My apologies. Updated answer.

Comment: It was the scalar context that was biting me. `print "Keys: "; 
        print keys($val);
        print "\n";` worked for me.

Comment: You should not be using experimental features that were deprecated 4 years ago and have already been removed from Perl!!! Please use `keys(%$val)` as I've instructed.

Comment: It's some legacy code that I'm attempting to debug otherwise fair point.